# Having a lot of difficulty with importing parts of Javascript library into a .html file

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, libraries

I've been having a lot of difficulty with trying to import parts of a Javascript library into a .html file. Everytime I fix a problem I run into a new one. I am currently running the .html file on a localhost after installing apache, but am getting two error messages in the console that I don't know how to fix when I try to install files from a Javascript library. These are the error messages:

Loading module from “http://localhost/js/core/MinimalStim” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost/js/core/MinimalStim”.

Loading module from “http://localhost/js/core/WindowMixin” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost/js/core/WindowMixin”.

Loading module from “http://localhost/js/util/Util” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost/js/util/Util”.

Loading module from “http://localhost/js/util/PsychObject” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost/js/util/PsychObject”. localhost:16:1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content = "ie=edge">
    <title>Today's date</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>"Today's date"</h1>
    <script src="js/visual/VisualStim.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="js/core/MinimalStim.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="js/core/WindowMixin.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="js/util/Util.js" type="module"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, is there anyway to install an entire library at a time rather than separate files from the library, because every time I try and import a file from that library, that file imports other files from the same library, meaning that I then have to import that file from the library as well. I can't find any information about this anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://parceljs.org/ or webpack to combine files and generate single. Parcel is light weighted. Can be done in minimal lines. WebPack required little effort to setup

`npm install -g parcel-bundler`

Regarding the loading issue, seems like you have to enable `apache static` server. Check your configuration.

Another reason could be PORT, by default port is 80. Try some other port.

[Serving static files through apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739925/serving-static-files-through-apache)

You can use `http-server`, `light weight` server to serve static contents.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server